# Sequelize association between Users, Employees, Customers, Sessions and Roles Table

Tags: sequelize.js, associations, model-associations

I am working on my first node application and designing database using Sequelize. I was able to define database structure easily using models but stuck in association phase. I spent decent amount on learning association, it does make sense but still not comfortable with it.

I also realized, I am unsure about the table relation after learning association, so I created a database manually using phpMyAdmin and then tried to replicate that in Sequelize. I was able to setup simple association between tables using trial and error method . Now, when I try to access the data using the association, it returns null. Which mean, my association is wrong.

**Table Structure:**

- **Users**: basic user information like name, email, mobile
- **Employees**: employee specific information like username, password
- **Customers**: hold customer specific data, e.g. life time sale
- **Roles**: role id and name
- **User_Roles**: user id and role id (junction table)
- **Session**: session info including user id or username and session token

The table structure can be visualized in the following image.

[image]

**Association**:

- **User & Roles**: Many-to-Many using junction table (user_roles)
- **User & Employees**: One-to-One
- **User & Customer**: One-to-One
- **Employee(User) & Session**: One(Many)-to-Many

**Association Code**:

```
role.belongsToMany(user, { through: "user_roles", foreignKey: "role_id", otherKey: "user_id" });
user.belongsToMany(role, { through: "user_roles", foreignKey: "user_id", otherKey: "role_id" });
user.hasOne(employee); 
employee.belongsTo(user); 
user.hasOne(customer); 
customer.belongsTo(user); 
user.belongsToMany(session, { through: "user_session", foreignKey: "user_id", otherKey: "session_id" }); 
session.belongsToMany(user, { through: "user_session", foreignKey: "session_id", otherKey: "user_id" });
```

**Crashing Problem:**
The crashing was result of foreign key check failure during the table removal. I was able to overcome that issue by manually deleting tables one-by-one and it worked with next association pattern.

**Questions**:

1. Does the relationship mentioned in the question are correct? (to
   clarify)
2. The relation between user and session table will be one-to-one or
   many-to-many?
3. Is there any particular order to consider for associations?

**Considering following relation:**

```
user.hasOne(employee);
employee.belongsTo(user);
```

1. Is there any built-in function to grab user from employee model? (like `Employee.getUser`)
2. What is the correct approach to create user and employee? (`User.create` and once it is created, `User.createEmployee` to create employee or how)
3. Is there any other way to create user and employee using single method? (for example, if I have list of user in JSON format then passing full object to a single method will make entries in both tables instead of calling them one after another)

PS: an explanation with the answer will clarify my concepts and help me avoid mistakes in the future.

Comment: I don't know why the line of code `user.hasOne(employee)` might cause an error....  What happens when the program crashes? Is there an error message?  Also, do you have a line like `employee.belongsTo(user)`?

Comment: @Andrew the crashing was result of trial and error method. During the table recreation process, some foreign key checks were failing and resulting in crash. I have updated question with more detail and my questions.